# How to add header or footer for printing with an extended richtextbox?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have an extended RichTextBox control that I can print from, using Microsoft's code. It works perfectly, and prints all the contents of my RichTextBox. However, what I would like to do is to add a header (one line static) or a footer to the printed output. Bonus if you could tell me how to add an additional page to the printed output!

```
Option Explicit On 


Public Class RichTextBoxPrintCtrl
  Inherits RichTextBox


  Private Const AnInch As Double = 14.4

  <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
   Private Structure RECT
     Public Left As Integer
     Public Top As Integer
     Public Right As Integer
     Public Bottom As Integer
  End Structure

  <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
  Private Structure CHARRANGE
     Public cpMin As Integer          ' First character of range (0 for start of doc)
     Public cpMax As Integer          ' Last character of range (-1 for end of doc)
  End Structure

  <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
  Private Structure FORMATRANGE
     Public hdc As IntPtr             ' Actual DC to draw on
     Public hdcTarget As IntPtr       ' Target DC for determining text formatting
     Public rc As Rect                ' Region of the DC to draw to (in twips)
     Public rcPage As Rect            ' Region of the whole DC (page size) (in twips)
     Public chrg As CHARRANGE         ' Range of text to draw (see above declaration)
  End Structure

  Private Const WM_USER As Integer = &H400
  Private Const EM_FORMATRANGE As Integer = WM_USER + 57

  Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "USER32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal msg As Integer, ByVal wp As IntPtr, ByVal lp As IntPtr) As IntPtr

  ' Render the contents of the RichTextBox for printing
  'Return the last character printed + 1 (printing start from this point for next page)
  Public Function Print(ByVal charFrom As Integer, ByVal charTo As Integer, ByVal e As PrintPageEventArgs) As Integer

     ' Mark starting and ending character 
     Dim cRange As CHARRANGE
     cRange.cpMin = charFrom
     cRange.cpMax = charTo

     ' Calculate the area to render and print
     Dim rectToPrint As RECT
     rectToPrint.Top = e.MarginBounds.Top * AnInch
     rectToPrint.Bottom = e.MarginBounds.Bottom * AnInch
     rectToPrint.Left = e.MarginBounds.Left * AnInch
     rectToPrint.Right = e.MarginBounds.Right * AnInch

     ' Calculate the size of the page
     Dim rectPage As RECT
     rectPage.Top = e.PageBounds.Top * AnInch
     rectPage.Bottom = e.PageBounds.Bottom * AnInch
     rectPage.Left = e.PageBounds.Left * AnInch
     rectPage.Right = e.PageBounds.Right * AnInch

     Dim hdc As IntPtr = e.Graphics.GetHdc()

     Dim fmtRange As FORMATRANGE
     fmtRange.chrg = cRange                 ' Indicate character from to character to 
     fmtRange.hdc = hdc                     ' Use the same DC for measuring and rendering
     fmtRange.hdcTarget = hdc               ' Point at printer hDC
     fmtRange.rc = rectToPrint              ' Indicate the area on page to print
     fmtRange.rcPage = rectPage             ' Indicate whole size of page

     Dim res As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero          

     Dim wparam As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
     wparam = New IntPtr(1)

     ' Move the pointer to the FORMATRANGE structure in memory
     Dim lparam As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
     lparam = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(fmtRange))
     Marshal.StructureToPtr(fmtRange, lparam, False)

     ' Send the rendered data for printing 
     res = SendMessage(Handle, EM_FORMATRANGE, wparam, lparam)

     ' Free the block of memory allocated
     Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(lparam)

     ' Release the device context handle obtained by a previous call
     e.Graphics.ReleaseHdc(hdc)

     ' Return last + 1 character printer
     Return res.ToInt32()
  End Function



Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
  ' Print the content of the RichTextBox. Store the last character printed.
  checkPrint = RichTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Print(checkPrint, RichTextBoxPrintCtrl1.TextLength, e)

  ' Look for more pages
  If checkPrint < RichTextBoxPrintCtrl1.TextLength Then
     e.HasMorePages = True
  Else
     e.HasMorePages = False
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it is quite easy to add a line of text. After some research on the Windows printing class, I have found that it is accomplished with:

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(("Header"), New Font("Arial", 16), Brushes.Black, 95, 70)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change *AnInch to a smaller measurement for both top and bottom.

Initialize the header / footer as a string.

Assign them to the top & bottom.

Comment: Thanks, I think I am following you, but how do I assign the string to the top?